# How do I reclaim my old Gmail username?

Tags: gmail, username

I'm looking to recover the username from a Google Account that I deleted a couple years ago.

The username is `stevenheidel`. All I want is the name, don't require any information from the account. This is the username I use for everything, so it'd be great if I could have the `@gmail.com` address back.

Comment: Have you contacted Google?

Comment: Good luck with that. Customer support is not a strong point of Google.

Comment: @Andris - Customer support *is* a strong point.  Google is really great at providing documentation for just about everything, evidenced by your answer linking to the policy of not re-creating the email address to thwart malicious users.  +1 for that answer, BTW.  :)

Comment: This is why I never delete anything :(  Of course, that has it's challenges too.  You could try stevenheidel1@gmail.com perhaps.  Also, just curious, why did you delete it in the first place?

Comment: I deleted it because this was way back when before there was spam filtering, and I was getting way too much spam.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately Google has a [policy](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66278) against reissuing deleted email addresses.
It makes sense since they can not verify if the user who wants to register a deleted email address is the original owner of that address or not. If they would allow this a malicious user could pretend to be the original owner by using his old email address.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, when you delete a Gmail account, you can still [recover your Gmail username](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=67422) with the Google account you used to create it, else it is lost forever. Indeed, for security purpose, a deleted username is locked to prevent a malicious impersonation or website account theft on other websites linked to the old Gmail account.